# Backup via SAS to Azure Blob not working

Tags: sql-server

I have changed my backups to go via Shared Access Signature rather than just a standard key (Microsofts preferred method).

However on a few large databases it fails after a while.

E.g. One database is 730GB and fails around 67%
SQL 2016, Standard Edition

Restored it to a SQL 2022 box and has the same problem. Error is something about device i/o error.

Other databases on the same boxes work perfectly fine

Ran CheckDB with extended logical checks and everything came back clear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Msg 3202, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Write on "https://<StorageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/backups/Test.bak" failed: 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.)